# extracting ranges using rowids from data.table

Tags: r, data.table

In the example shown below, I would like to use the columns in `sel.dt` as start and end to extract rows from `data.dt`.  So, I would like to create a datatable which has the following rows from `data.dt`: `(11, 12, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 58, 59, ...)`

```
require(data.table)

N <- 10000
data.dt <- data.table(id=sample(1:100, N, replace=TRUE), cost=runif(N,100,200))
sel.dt <- data.table(i=sample(5:60,10,replace=TRUE))[, j:=i+sample(1:10,10,replace=TRUE)]

> data.dt
       id     cost
    1: 24 114.2434
    2: 14 104.7751
    3: 99 103.2048
    4: 49 187.9645
    ..............

> sel.dt
     i  j
 1: 11 12
 2:  8 14
 3: 58 59
 ........
```

Comment: Do you want it grouped by selection ranges? If not, the base solution still works: `data.dt[with(sel.dt, unlist(Map(seq, from = i, to = j))), ]` Btw, you should use set.seed before making a random example so we're all looking at the same thing

Comment: Thanks.  Wondering if there is a `data.table` approach like `sel.dt[, list(x=seq.int(i,j,1L))]` which would get the list of row indexes.  That statement comes back with the error `'from' must be of length 1`.

Comment: The error explains what the problem is, right? You could do it by row, `sel.dt[, list(x=seq.int(i,j,1L)), by=1:nrow(sel.dt)]` so that `i` and `j` are both length 1.

Comment: or copying Frank's `i` code into `j` as follows: `sel.dt[, unlist(Map(seq, from=i, to=j))]`

Comment: Hint: try `nonequi` join. That's the latest data.table way of doing what you want.